# Post upgrade to 5.8, Javascripts running in Drupal are failing with CRM is not defined

Tags: drupal, javascript

Both on drupal blocks where references to CRM.$ are used and in custom javascripts that call CRM.api3, the scripts are failing and displaying an Uncaught Exception: CRM is not defined.  Everything worked previously with 4.6.38